# Can't see a custom template in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a custom *File Template* for a special type of a Java class commonly used in my project.

I went to *Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates*, copied the *Class* template and customised the code.

[image]

However, I cannot see the new file type in the *New File* menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I misunderstood the way these templates are supposed to be used. I found the answer in the [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-template-based-files.html).

> If required, specify the *kind* of the new template-based file. For example, if you select Java class, you'll be able to create a **Java class**, *interface, enumeration, annotation, etc.;* if you select to create an **HTML file**, you'll be able to create *HTML, HTML4, or XHTML* file. In other words, use one of the corresponding related file templates.

There seems to be only one item in this menu for every file type. My custom template was registered but it's only available as a *Kind* of a *Java Class*. It's available in the popup menu that appears once I try to create a *Java Class*.

[image: Menu option to create a new Java Class]

[image: Java file 'Kind' selection]

Comment: Answering your own post within 4 seconds of posting the question. Well done!.

Comment: @LukeMelaia technically, that was an immediate [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I came up with the solution before I finished writing the question on SO but I decided to post it for others to find.